# Como criar mais de um gráfico no matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Preciso criar gráficos de histogramas em python com listas resultantes de transformações. Minha duvida é que sempre que rodo o programa, a imagem seguinte só aparece depois que fecho a anterior.

```
transformacaoEscala(U,V,n,a,b)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=80)
histogram(V,12)
plt.show()
somaVetores(U1,U2,U,n)
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=80)
histogram(U,10)
plt.show()
```

Como faco para criar imagens que apareçam separadamente?

Comment: A sua dúvida é como colocar os histogramas em uma única figura (imagem)?

Answer (score 1):

Deves utilizar o comando [subplot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot) para cada gráfico, um exemplo da sua utilização pode ser este:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f(t):
    return np.exp(-t) * np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.1)
t2 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.02)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'bo', t2, f(t2), 'k')

plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(t2, np.cos(2*np.pi*t2), 'r--')
plt.show()
```

Tal como apresentado [aqui](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes). Sendo que o 1º algarismo corresponde ao número de linhas de gráficos, o 2º o número de colunas e o 3º corresponde ao número de cada gráfico.